# Accepted answers don't float "on top" when self-answered?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, accepted-answer, sorting, self-answer

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267113/how-to-implement-an-inherited-dictionary-over-wcf), the accepted answer doesn't float on top. Apart from that, the display is correct (i.e. the V mark and the green border).

If I sort by "vote", I've got the following answer order:

- Jezell
- Marc Gravell
- chilltemp (Accepted)
- Shaun Bowe

By "oldest":

- Marc Gravell
- Jezell
- chilltemp (Accepted)
- Shaun Bowe

and by "newest":

- Shaun Bowe
- chilltemp (Accepted)
- Jezell
- Marc Gravell

---

I'm using Firefox V.3.5 : Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1) Gecko/20090624 Firefox/3.5 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)

Feel free to ask for more debug information if needed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is intentional. The post author has selected an answer they wrote as the accepted answer, and therefore it [does not change the sort order](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) of the posts.

Comment: IMO, this rule does not make sense. The answer marked as solution by the asker should be pinned to top, no matter who submitted it. The asker knows best. I've seen many cases where the answer marked as solution IS the correct solution. Voting for an answer is often simply a casual "i like this", not "i believe this is the solution".

Answer (score 1):

Since September 2021, accepted answers are unpinned on many sites, including Stack Overflow.  For details, see: *[Outdated Answers: accepted answer is now unpinned on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411352/974555)*.

On those sites, it no longer matters for sorting order whether a question is self-answered or not.