# Why do upvoted answers sometimes get buried?

Tags: bug, up-votes, sorting

It's my understanding that upvoted questions should be on top. But in this page an 1800 upvote answer is halfway down a pretty long page, and the accepted answer is towards the bottom!

[.gitignore is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451535/gitignore-is-not-working)

Is this a bug? Is this only showing up for me for some reason?

Comment: Change the page sorting to votes, top right above the answers. Now the highest voted answer will be on top. The accept only shows an answer worked for the OP, not that it is best.

Comment: [sort on votes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451535/gitignore-is-not-working?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Accepted self-answers, unlike other accepted answers, don't sort any differently than the score/age/activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've probably sorted the answers by latest activity:

> [image]

Then the most recent active answer (the one that was posted or edited the most recently) will be on top no matter how many votes it has. This means that since several new answers have been posted and/or edited since the last time the one with 1870 upvotes was edited, that answer got buried under all the new answers.

What you want is probably to sort them by votes. To do that, click on the "votes" tab:

> [image]

As you can see, the answer with 1870 upvotes is now on top.

When you sort the answers by votes, the accepted answer will usually be pinned on top no matter how many votes it has. But in this specific case, the accepted answer was posted by the same user who posted the question, and when that's the case, the accepted answer isn't pinned on top but sorted by votes just like any other answer. The reason why is explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93213/349538).

Comment: I like the freehand circles.